# Use javascript validation only in safari

Tags: javascript, html, validation, google-chrome, safari

I have build a form that use the HTML5 Form Validation but it is not supported in safari.
So I made a simple javascript thath works fine.
Now I'd like to use the HTML5 Form Validation in all browser that support this and use the javascript in the others.
How can I do this ceck?

This is my form code (not all, only the important part):

```
<form action="www.xyz.com" method="post" >
<div id="form">
<input type="text" class="input" name="c209" id="nome" placeholder="Nome*" tabindex="1" required="required" x-moz-errormessage="Invalid name"/></input>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="INVIA" id="submit" onclick="return validate(nome)"/>
</div>
</form>
```

and this is the script code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate () {
  var valid = true;
  var msg="Attenzione!\n";
    if ( document.getElementById('nome').value == "" ) {
    msg+="-Campo nome non compilato\n";
    valid = false;
  if (!valid)
  {
    alert(msg);
    return false;
  }
return valid;
}
</script>
</head>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no closing tag for input elements, nor any short tag notation in HTML. The google–chrome tag seems inappropriate. You should not have any form control named "submit" as it masks the form's submit method, and validation should be on the form's submit handler, not the button's.

Answer (score 1):

```
var field = document.getElementById('nome').willValidate;
```

- true when the browser will natively validate the field
- false when the browser will not validate the field
- undefined when the browser does not support native HTML5 validation, e.g. IE8.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/constraints.html#the-constraint-validation-api

```
if (typeof field !== "undefined") {

   // native validation available

} else {

    // native validation not available

}
```

Comment: I added it to my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Actually, this will only tell wether form validation API is availabe. But not wether the browser will interactivley validate the form. Although in theory there shouldn't be a difference, it's a big difference in real world. If you want to test this in real worl you might want to check how modernizr is doing that: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/forms/validation.js